# Can't Click on JButton in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, jframe, jbutton

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
  //Create a Frame
  JFrame m_MainFrame = new JFrame();
  m_MainFrame.setSize(800, 800);
  m_MainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
  m_MainFrame.setLayout(null);
  //Create a Panel
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  p.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 200);
  // Create a Button
  final JButton button = new JButton("test ");
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
     {
        if (ae.getSource() == button) {
           System.out.println("Button Pressed ");
        }
     }
  });
  p.add(button);
  m_MainFrame.add(p);
  m_MainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The above codes is a simple test program I've used to test but fail to work(Can't click anything in the Frame) on a Ubuntu 12.04 with

java version "1.6.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

I'm curious whether it's the problem with the jdk used as I've tested and working with other Ubuntu pc with same version of OS.

Does anyone know what may be the cause for my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine, running under Windows with Eclipse java 1.6. What do you mean by "can't click"? You may change "getSource() == button" to "getSource().equals(button)"

Comment: @Devolus Thanks for the reply.Actually after few tests I've done, I think there should be something wrong with my OS or jdk as I've tested with several version of Ubuntu and jdk, but it just doesn't work with the PC of Ubuntu 12.04 + jdk 1.6.0_25.The "can't click" just simply mean by the words.The button doesn't even show focused when i mouse-over it, and doesn't response at all when i clicked it.

Comment: if the answer was right you should mark and upvote please

Comment: There must be something wrong with your java, it works fine in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `button.setEnabled(true);` - You have initialized the button but I couldn't see you setting it Enabled. Hope this help.